# Moving multiple files having spaces in name (Linux)

Tags: linux, shell, find, move

I have a directory which contains multiple files with spaces in their names. I want to find a pattern in the name and those file will be moved to some other directory. Now the problem is that when the particular pattern is found in a single file name, that file is moving to the destination path but when there are multiple files this method fails. Below is the code that I'm using :

```
for file in `find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*$pattern*xlsx" -type f`
do
 mv "$file" $destination/
done
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to use a loop:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*$pattern*xlsx" -type f -exec mv {} $destination +
```

Answer (score 4):

Working fine with following code

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*$pattern*xlsx" -type f -print0 | xargs -I{} -0 mv {} "$destination/"
```

Comment: I'm afraid your solution is longer, more complex, less portable (uses non POSIX `find` and `xargs` extensions) and (slightly) less efficient than using `find` alone.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, the logic to insert in the body of the loop could be complex enough to warrant an actual bash loop.

Here is a solution that works that way:

```sh
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*$pattern*xlsx" -type f | while IFS= read -r file
do
   mv "$file" $destination/
done
```

Edit: kudos to @KamilCuk for the `IFS=`, to handle filenames with leading and trailing whitespace, and `-r`, to handle filenames with escaped backspace characters.

Known limitation: this solution will not work for filenames that have embedded newlines. For such cases, see the other answers to this question.

Solution from @Charles Duffy in comments to [Moving files with whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64794294/3216427) what will work even with newlines in the file names:

- add `-print0` to the `find` command to terminate records with the NULL character
- add `-d ''` to the `read` command to read records terminated by NULL

```sh
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*$pattern*xlsx" -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
   mv "$file" $destination/
done
```

Comment: Well, it's worth noting that this code will incorrectly handle files with leading and trailing spaces and files with \ baskspace characters... Anyway, use `while read file` to read words, use `while IFS= read -r file` to read lines (which still will incorrectly handle filenames with newlines). See [bashfaq how to read a stream line by line](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks for the precisions! I'll fix my answer to incorporate your corrections.

Comment: As for newline inside a filename, my first reaction was "whoever does that?", but it's good to be aware it's a limitation. I prefer code that works all the time, whenever possible. So thanks for that too.

Comment: Found comment in other post to solve newlines in file names, so I've added that to my answer, which I've turned into a community wiki, since it's now combining ideas from three of us.

Answer (score 0):

The top answer `find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*$pattern*xlsx" -type f -exec mv {} $destination +` isn't working for me, and the man pages of `find -exec command {} +` state the following:

> one  instance
> of  `{}'  is  allowed within the command, and it must appear at the end, immediately before the `+'

So instead I propose:
`find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*$pattern*xlsx" -type f -exec mv -t ../All\ Exercises/ {} +`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).