# How can I make a bash script where I can move certain files to certain folders which are named based on a string in the files?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, automation

This is the script that I'm using to move files with the string "john" in them (124334_john_rtx.mp4 , 3464r64_john_gty.mp4 etc) to a certain folder

```
find /home/peter/Videos -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*john' -print0 | \
xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty echo mv --target-directory=/home/peter/Videos/john/
```

Since I have a large amount of videos with various names written in the files, I want to make a bash script which moves videos with a string between the underscores to a folder named based on the string between the underscores. So for example if a file is named 4345655_ben_rts.mp4 the script would identify the string "ben" between the underscores, create a folder named as the string between the underscores which in this case is "ben" and move the file to that folder. Any advice is greatly appreciated !

Comment: This answer to a different question might help you partially: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64826172/3216427 It solves creating a bash loop from your `find` command, do you need help extracting the substring from the file name too?

Comment: if either answer below was helpful, please consider accepting the one that best solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This bash loop should do what you need:

```sh
find dir -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*mp4' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
    if [[ $file =~ _([^_]+)_ ]]; then
        TARGET_DIR="/PARENTPATH/${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        mkdir -p "$TARGET_DIR"
        mv "$file" "$TARGET_DIR"
    fi
done
```

It'll only move the files if it finds a directory token.

I used `_([^_]+)_` to make sure there is no `_` in the dir name, but you didn't specify what you want if there are more than two `_` in the file name. `_(.+)_` will work if `foo_bar_baz_buz.mp4` is meant to go into directory `bar_baz`.

And this answer to a different question explains the `find | while` logic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64826172/3216427 .

EDIT: As per a question in the comments, I added `mkdir -p` to create the target directory. The `-p` means recursively create any part of the path that doesn't already exist, and will not error out if the full directory already exists.

Comment: It works thank you ! But it only works if I create the folder before hand with that string. How can I edit the mv line so it creates a new folder named as the string ? I tried putting mkdir in there but it didn't work

Comment: @bennyblanco You can add a `mkdir -p` statement before `mv`, like in @Funkynene's solution below. I'll add that to my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

My way to do it :

```
cd /home/peter/Videos # Change directory to your start directory
for name in $(ls *.mp4 | cut -d'_' -f2 | sort -u)  # loops on a list of names after the first underscore
do
    mkdir -p /home/peter/Videos/${name}  # create the target directory if it doesn't exist
    mv *_${name}_*.mp4 /home/peter/Videos/${name}  # Moving the files
done
```